# When is the adjoint to a monoidal functor monoidal?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal C,\mathcal D$ be monoidal categories.  Recall that a functor $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is *lax monoidal* if it is equipped with maps $1_{\mathcal D} \to F(1_{\mathcal C})$ and $F(X) \otimes_{\mathcal D} F(Y) \to F(X \otimes_{\mathcal C} Y)$, the latter natural in $X,Y\in \mathcal C$, compatible with associators and unitors.  It is *oplax monoidal* if it is instead equipped with maps in the other direction, and *strong monoidal* if it is equipped with isomorphisms.  For each choice of lax/oplax/strong, there is a bicategory of monoidal categories, lax/oplax/strong monoidal functors, and monoidal natural transformations.

Suppose that $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is one of lax/oplax/strong monoidal, and also admits a left adjoint $F^L$ in the bicategory of all functors.  Under what circumstances is $F^L$ naturally lax/oplax/strong monoidal?  Under what circumstances does this adjunction come from an adjunction in the bicategory of monoidal categories and lax/oplax/strong monoidal functors?

Comment: Of course, the answer will probably be different for different ordered pairs in {lax,oplax,strong}.  For example, if $F$ is lax, it is not too hard to believe that $F^L$ is oplax, based on the way that adjoints work (e.g. we do have a canonical map $F^L(1_D) \to 1_C$ corresponding to $1_D \to F(1_C)$).

Comment: If $F$ is lax $F^L = L$ is oplax via $L1 \rightarrow 1$ that you referred to, and the $L(X\otimes Y) \rightarrow L(FLX\otimes FLY) \rightarrow LF(LX\otimes LY) \rightarrow LX\otimes LY$. Nothing else is granted. In particular, if $F$ is strong, then $L$ is only oplax, and this is necessarily the only situation when we have an adjoint pair of oplax functors.

Comment: This is a old standard question, this is generalizable also to (op)lax.functors (see a bicategory as a monoidal with many objects). Do you read Italian? (I wrote about..)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $L$ and $R$ are a left and right adjoint, then [doctrinal adjunction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrinal+adjunction) asserts that $L$ is oplax monoidal iff $R$ is lax monoidal. (I'm being a bit imprecise here, treating monoidality as if it were a property instead of a structure, but hopefully the meaning is clear.)

Comment: Doctrinal adjunction also answers the second question: if $R$ is lax, then its left adjoint $L$ is automatically oplax, and the whole adjunction lifts to an adjunction in the 2-category of lax monoidal functors iff $L$ is actually *strong* (i.e. its canonically induced oplax structure maps are invertible).