# Oplax monoidal functors of $\infty$-categories

Tags: higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, adjoint-functors, higher-algebra, symmetric-monoidal-categories

In *Higher Algebra*, a notion of lax symmetric monoidal functors (in what follows, I'll remove the adjective "symmetric", but I'm mainly interested in the symmetric situation) is defined : if you have two  monoïdal $\infty$-categories $\mathscr{C^\otimes,D^\otimes}$, a lax monoidal functor is a map of $\infty$-operads $\mathscr{C^\otimes\to D^\otimes}$.

The fact that it's a map of $\infty$-operads and not of monoidal $\infty$-categories encodes the fact that $F(x)\otimes F(y) \to F(x\otimes y)$ is not necessarily an equivalence (it would be if we required $F$ to preserve all coCartesian arrows)

However, the word "oplax" doesn't even appear in HA and (although I can't say I have read all of it) I haven't seen anything in the book that would define the notion of oplax monoidal functor. Moreover, it's not clear to me how to encode that structure in terms of operads : a natural map $F(x\otimes y)\to F(x)\otimes F(y)$ somehow corresponds (in terms of operads) to a map $Multi(F(x),F(y); -) \to Multi(x,y;-)$, which therefore goes in the "wrong direction" (so the notion isn't simply a matter of removing some properties of a symmetric monoidal functor, as far as I can see)

So my first question is:

> Is there a reasonable, well-behaved notion of oplax monoidal functors in the setting of monoidal $\infty$-categories ?

("well-behaved" contains at least two requirements in my mind : 1- the notion of oplax monoidal functors should induce [ of course not be restricted to ] a natural transformation $F(x\otimes y)\to F(x)\otimes F(y)$; and 2- if this natural transformation is a natural equivalence, then in fact the functor "is" symmetric monoidal, whatever "is" could mean in this context - I don't necessarily expect oplax monoidal functors to be the same kind of datum as symmetric monoidal functors, so "is" could be anything from a literal "is" to "can canonically yield a" )

Assuming the answer to that question is "yes", I'm also interested in finding out whether something like "a left adjoint to a lax monoidal functor is oplax monoidal" (see e.g. the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212037/when-is-the-adjoint-to-a-monoidal-functor-monoidal), or the nLab page [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oplax+monoidal+functor) - of course there is an abuse of terminology here as well, because it shouldn't be "is", but something like "can be equipped with a canonical oplax monoidal structure")

So my second question is :

> Let $\mathscr{C^\otimes,D^\otimes}$, and $R^\otimes : \mathscr C^\otimes \to \mathscr D^\otimes$ be a lax monoidal functor, assume the induced functor $R : \mathscr C\to \mathscr D$ has a left adjoint $L$. Then can $L$ be canonically equipped with an oplax monoidal structure ?

Ideally, this oplax monoidal functor would have the feature that the induced natural transformation $L(x\otimes y)\to L(x)\otimes L(y)$ is induced by $x\otimes y \to RL(x)\otimes RL(y) \to R(L(x)\otimes L(y))$, as in the usual case.

If it can help at all, the specific adjunction I'm interested in is a colocalization, in that the left adjoint is fully-faithful (at the level of the underlying $\infty$-categories), so if the general result doesn't quite hold, but does hold in that specific case, I'm interested as well. However, it's not clear in my situation that the monoidal structure is induced by said colocalization, so I can't really restrict to that sort of situation.

Comment: Isn't an oplax monoidal functor just a lax monoidal functor between the opposite categories?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd : I just made a fool of myself, didn't I ? You're right, this is correct in the $1$-categorical case, and it surely extends quite easily here too. Then the result about adjunctions, at least for colocalizations, follows from the one for localizations and lax monoidal functors

Comment: I don't think you made a fool of yourself. Not being an expert in $\infty$-categories, I for instance cannot answer your question about whether adjoints to lax monoidal functors are oplax monoidal, nor about whether to improve an (op)lax monoidal functor to a strong monoidal functor is merely property (some naturality morphism being iso) or data.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd : well I've been told that going from lax to strict is indeed a property, and I can see how the proof would go (coCartesian morphisms lying above $\langle 2 \rangle \to \langle 1\rangle$ are precisely morphisms that correspond to an equivalence of type $z\simeq x\otimes y$, so preservation of coCartesian morphisms amounts to preservation of tensor products, and you can generalize this), so if oplax = lax^op, it follows for oplax as well.

Comment: As for adjunctions, I have a slight doubt : in the case of reflexive localizations I know that if the monoidal structure on the localization is induced from the one on the original category, then the inclusion is lax monoidal, so I guess it should work for colocalization and oplax - but I'm not sure how that works when the monoidal structure is not induced from the other (although if you work naively, it should work). I guess I'll leave the question up to see if people have something interesting to say about this issue

Comment: I am confused by a previous comment. How to take op of an operad (and in particular, a symmetric monoidal category)?

Comment: @Z.M : I don't think you can op an operad, but a symmetric monoidal category can be seen as a commutative monoid in $Cat_\infty$ and you can apply op pointwise - this preserves products, hence commutative monoids.